# Why does MATLAB throw a "too many output arguments" error when I overload subsref (subscripted reference)?

Tags: matlab, operator-overloading

As a **toy example**, I have a class that simply wraps a vector or matrix in an object and includes a timestamp of when it was created. I'm trying to overload `subsref` so that

1. `()` referencing works exactly as it does with the standard vector and matrix types
2. `{}` referencing works in *exactly* the same way as `()` referencing (nothing to do with cells in other words)
3. `.` referencing allows me to access the **private** properties of the object and other fields that aren't technically properties.

Code:

```
classdef TimeStampValue

    properties (Access = private)
        time;
        values;
    end

    methods
        %% Constructor
        function x = TimeStampValue(values)
            x.time = now();
            x.values = values;
        end

        %% Subscripted reference
        function x = subsref(B, S)
            switch S.type
                case '()'
                    v = builtin('subsref', B.values, S);
                    x = TimeStampValue(v);
                case '{}'
                    S.type = '()';
                    v = builtin('subsref', B.values, S);
                    x = TimeStampValue(v);
                case '.'
                    switch S.subs
                        case 'time'
                            x = B.time;
                        case 'values'
                            x = B.values;
                        case 'datestr'
                            x = datestr(B.time);
                    end
            end
        end

        function disp(x)
            fprintf('\t%d\n', x.time)
            disp(x.values)
        end   

    end

end
```

However brace `{}` referencing doesn't work. I run this code

```
clear all
x = TimeStampValue(magic(3));
x{1:2}
```

and I get this error:

```
Error using TimeStampValue/subsref
Too many output arguments.
Error in main (line 3)
x{1:2}
```

`MException.last` gives me this info:

```
identifier: 'MATLAB:maxlhs'
   message: 'Too many output arguments.'
     cause: {0x1 cell}
     stack: [1x1 struct]
```

which isn't helpful because the only thing in the exception stack is the file containing three lines of code that I ran above.

I placed a breakpoint on the first line of the switch statement in `subsref` but MATLAB never reaches it.

Whats the deal here? Both `()` and `.` referencing work as you would expect, so why doesn't `{}` referencing work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When overloading the curly braces `{}` to return a different number of output arguments than usual, it is also necessary to overload `numel` to return the intended number (1, in this case). **UPDATE:** As of **R2015b**, the new function **[`numArgumentsFromSubscript`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numargumentsfromsubscript.html)** was created to be overloaded instead of `numel`.  The issue remains the same, but this function should be overloaded instead of `numel` as I describe in the original answer below.  See also the page ["Modify nargout and nargin for Indexing Methods"](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/overloading-numel-subsref-and-subsasgn.html).  Excerpt:

> When a class overloads `numArgumentsFromSubscript`, MATLAB calls this method instead of `numel` to compute the number of arguments expected for `subsref` `nargout` and `subsasgn` `nargin`.
>
> If classes do not overload `numArgumentsFromSubscript`, MATLAB calls `numel` to compute the values of `nargout` or `nargin`.

More explanation of the underlying issue (need to specify number of output arguments) follows.

---

**Original answer (use `numArgumentsFromSubscript` instead of `numel` for R2015b+)**

To handle the possibility of a comma separated list of output arguments when indexing with curly braces, MATLAB calls `numel` to determine the number of output arguments from the size of the input indexes (according to [this MathWorks answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101955#answer_111302)). If the number of output arguments in the definition of overloaded `subsref` is inconsistent with (i.e. less than) the number provided by `numel`, you get the "Too many output arguments" error.  As stated by MathWorks:

> Therefore, to allow curly brace indexing into your object while returning a number of arguments INCONSISTENT with the size of the input, you will need to overload the NUMEL function inside your class directory.

Since `x{1:2}` normally provides two outputs (`X{1},X{2}`), the definition `function x = subsref(B, S)` is incompatible for this input. The solution is to include in the class a simple `numel` method to overload the builtin function, as follows:

```matlab
function n = numel(varargin)
    n = 1;
end
```

Now the `{}` indexing works as intended, mimicking `()`:

```
>> clear all % needed to reset the class definition
>> x = TimeStampValue(magic(3));
>> x(1:2)
ans = 
    7.355996e+05
     8     3
>> x{1:2}
ans = 
    7.355996e+05
     8     3
```

However, overloading curly braces in this manner is [apparently](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101955#answer_111302) a "specific type of code that we [MathWorks] did not expect customers to be writing". MathWorks recommends:

> If you are designing your class to output only one argument, it is not recommended that you use curly brace indexing that requires you to overload NUMEL. Instead, it is recommended you use smooth brace () indexing.

**UPDATE:** Interestingly, the [R2015b release notes state](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#bu0biit-3):

> Before MATLAB release R2015b, MATLAB incorrectly computed the number of arguments expected for outputs from `subsref` and inputs to `subsasgn` for some indexing expressions that return or assign to a comma-separated list.
>
> With release R2015b, MATLAB correctly computes the values of `nargout` and `nargin` according to the number of arguments required by the indexing expression.

So perhaps this is now fixed?

---

An alternative solution that comes to mind is to change `function x = subsref(B, S)` to `function varargout = subsref(B, S)` and adding `varargout=cell(1,numel(B)); varargout{1} = x;`. As Amro noted in comments, pre-allocating the cell is necessary to avoid an error about an unassigned argument.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Mathworks never thought that people would want to overload both `subsref` and `numel`? That seems surprising. In my toy example, I would prefer to overload `subsref` as I've done, while still having `numel` return... the number of elements in the `values` property. I guess that's not possible.

Comment: @user30588 Yeah, that's a drag. I guess that's why they recommend "smooth" braces instead. I think it was actually an oversight on Mathworks' part.

Comment: It seems like it. My point was just that intuitively, overloading `subsref` (specifically curly brace indexing) should have *nothing to do with `numel`.* In this case, yes, I could easily just use `()` instead of `{}` for subscripted reference, but if I wanted to write a class where `{}` was completely, *logically* separate from indexing into an array, *but I still wanted `numel` to work as normal*, that functionality is broken in MATLAB. Seems strange to me.

Comment: With regard to the alternative solution, if you add the line `varargout=cell(1,numel(B));` (using the default `numel`) before the line `varargout{1}=x;` then you may avoid the unassigned output problem.

Comment: @gnovice Thanks for the suggestion. I added updated the answer (better late than never, I suppose).

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem. What's even worse, is that the number of output arguments is enforced to be equal to what `numel()` returns not only for the curly braces `{}`, but also for the dot `.` operation.

This means that if `numel()` is overridden to return the usual `prod(size(obj))`, it becomes impossible to access any properties of the underlying object (such as `x.time` in the above example), as `subsref()` is then expected to return *multiple* outputs.

But if `numel()` just returns 1 instead, it does not match `prod(size(obj))`, which is what most code working with numeric values or based on `reshape()` expects. In fact, the MATLAB editor's balloon help immediately suggests that 'NUMEL(x) is usually faster than PROD(SIZE(x))', which suggest that they are equivalent, but apparently are not.

A possible solution would be to make `numel()` return `prod(size(obj))` and write explicit getter/setter functions for all these properties, e.g.,

```
x.get_time()
```

in the example above. This seems to work, because method calls apparently get resolved before `subsref()` gets called. But then if one of the properties is a matrix it cannot be directly indexed any more because Matlab doesn't understand chained indexing, i.e., instead of writing

```
x.matrix(1,:)
```

one would have to write

```
m = x.get_matrix();
m(1,:)
```

which is ugly to say the least.

This is starting to get a bit frustrating. I still hope I've just overlooked something obvious, I can't believe that this is how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

This solution seems to work in 2014b (but not entirely certain why)

```
classdef TestClass < handle
    methods

        function n = numel(~,varargin)
            n = 1;
        end

        function varargout = subsref(input,S)
            varargout = builtin('subsref',input,S);
        end

        function out = twoOutputs(~)
            out = {}; out{1} = 2; out{2} = 3; 
        end
    end
end
```

Then via the command window

```
>> testClass = TestClass();
>> [a,b] = testClass.twoOutouts()
a =

     2

b =

     3
```

Comment: My office is getting 2014b sometime this month, so I'll test this out and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a class to handle polynomials and polynomial matrices. I was having the same dificulty because I want different behaviors for the `'.'` indexing in the cases of scalar polynomials and polynomial matrices.

In my case I want `P.coef` to return a vector of coefficients if `P` is a scalar polynomial. If `P` is a polynomial matrix, `P.coef` must return a cell array of the same size of `P`, in which the cell `{i,j}` contains the coefficient vector of the polynomial `P(i,j)`.

The problem appeared when `P.coef` was used with a matrix. My desired behavior returns only one object as an answer, but Matlab is expecting the function to return `numel(P)` objects.

I found a very simple solution. When declaring `subsref`, I used one mandatory output and a `varargout`:

```
function [R,varargout] = subsref(P,S)
```

The body of the function defines `R` as needed, according to my design. And at the very end of the function I added:

```
varargout(1:nargout-1) = cell(1,nargout-1);
```

To just return empty matrices as the extra outputs that Matlab wants.

This should create no problem if the function is always called with a single output argument, e.g., as in `R = P.coef`. If the function is called without assigning, the user will see `numel(P)-1` empty matrices, which is really not a big deal. Anyway, the user is warned about this in the function help.