# Trimming vals in a matrix of arbitrary dimensions in a specified dimension

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a function that requires some values in a matrix of arbitrary dimansions to be dropped in a specified dimension.

For example, say I have a 3x3 matrix:

```
a=[1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9];
```

I might want to drop the third element in each row, in which case I could do

```
a = a(:,1:2)
```

But what if the dimensions of a are arbitrary, and the dimension to trim is defined as an argument in the function?

Using linear indexing, and some carefully considered maths is an option but I was wondering if there is a neater soltion?

For those interested, this is my current code:

```
...
% Find length in each dimension
sz = size(dat);
% Get the proportion to trim in each dimension
k = sz(d)*abs(p);
% Get the decimal part and integer parts of k
int_part = fix(k);
dec_part = abs(k - int_part);

% Sort the array
dat = sort(dat,d);
% Trim the array in dimension d
if (int_part ~=0)
    switch d
       case 1
          dat = dat(int_part + 1 : sz(1) - int_part,:);
       case 2
          dat = dat(:,int_part + 1 : sz(2) - int_part);
    end
end
...
```

Comment: Can't you provide an example with arbitrary dimensions?

Comment: Dan, that makes no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't get any neater than this:

```
function A = trim(A, n, d)
%// Remove n-th slice of A in dimension d
%// n can be vector of indices. d needs to be scalar

sub = repmat({':'}, 1, ndims(A));
sub{d} = n;
A(sub{:}) = [];
```

This makes use of the not very well known fact that the *string* `':'` can be used as an index. With due credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22539481/2586922) by @AndrewJanke, and to @chappjc for [bringing it to my attention](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2778484/chappjc).

Answer (score 0):

```
a = a(:, 1:end-1)
```

`end`, used as a matrix index, always refers to the index of the last element of that matrix

if you want to trim different dimensions, the simplest way is using and if/else block - as MatLab only supports 7 dimensions at most, you wont need an infinite number of these to cover all bases

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm currently doing, but it looks pretty ugly :-(

Comment: I dont think this works in general. For example, if A is 2x3x4, your answer gives a 2x11 matrix. Also, it's not true that Matlab only allows 7 dimensions. Sorry, but downvoting

Comment: My bad, the seven dimensions must be from c#. Its a bit much to expect one line that does any arbitrary number of dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

The `permute` function allows to permute the dimension of an array of any dimension.
You can place the dimension you want to trim in a prescribed position (the first, I guess), trim, and finally restore the original ordering. In this way you can avoid running loops and do what you want compactly.