# Extract one dimension from a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

Suppose `A` is multi-dimensional array (MDA) of size `3,4,5` and `B` is another MDA of size `3,4,5,6`.

I know `A(1,:,:)` or `B(1,:,:,:)` can both extract their elements along the first dimension.

I now need to write a general program to extract the `k-th` dimension from a MDA without knowing its size.

For example, the MDA `C` has `6` dimension: `4,5,6,7,8,9` and I want an extraction `C(:,:,k,:,:,:)`.

Sometimes, the MDA 'D' has `4` dimension: `3,4,5,6` and I want another extraction `D(k,:,:,:)`.

That is, my problem is the numbers of `colon` is varying because of the dimension.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string arrays to index the array dynamically:

```
function out = extract(arr,dim,k)  

    subses = repmat({':'}, [1 ndims(arr)]);
    subses(dim) = num2cell(k);
    out = arr(subses{:});
```

where `dim` is the dimension in which you want to select and `k` is an index within that dimension.

I have used a code from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27975910/3399825

Comment: thanks addy, it works!