# How to crop matrix of any number of dimensions in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, crop

Suppose I have 4D matrix:

```
>> A=1:(3*4*5*6);
>> A=reshape(A,3,4,5,6);
```

And now I want to cut given number of rows and columns (or any given chunks at known dimensions).

If I would know it's 4D I would write:

```
>> A1=A(1:2,1:3,:,:);
```

But how to write universally for any given number of dimensions?

The following gives something different:

```
>> A2=A(1:2,1:3,:);
```

And the following gives an error:

```
>> A2=A;
>> A2(3:3,4:4)=[];
```

Comment: A minor modification of [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22537326/2586922) will work

Comment: To make sure I understand this correctly - the problem is that you don't know in advance how many `,:` you'll need in the indexing expression...? Also I'm assuming you meant "any given number of dimensions >=2"...?

Comment: @Dev-iL yes this is it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to generate a code with general number of dimension of `A` using the second form of indexing you used and reshape function.
Here there is an example:

```
Asize = [3,4,2,6,4]; %Initialization of A, not seen by the rest of the code
A = rand(Asize);

%% This part of the code can operate for any matrix A
I = 1:2;
J = 3:4;
A1 = A(I,J,:);
NewSize = size(A);
NewSize(1) = length(I);
NewSize(2) = length(J);
A2 = reshape(A1,NewSize);
```

`A2` will be your cropped matrix. It works for any `Asize` you choose.

Comment: A modification of this might work...OP doesn't know "Asize", so needs to use ndims (or check the length of size(A) ) and act accordingly.

Comment: Ah thanks for the tip. Now it should work even not knowing `Asize`.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend the solution Luis Mendo suggested for the general case, but there is also a very simple solution when you know a upper limit for your dimensions. Let's assume you have at most 6 dimensions. Use 6 dimensional indexing for all matrices:

```
A1=A(1:2,1:3,:,:,:,:);
```

Matlab will implicit assume singleton dimensions for all remaining dimension, returning the intended result also for matrices with less dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to use ndims.

```
num_dimensions = ndims(A)

if (num_dimensions == 3)
    A1 = A(1:2, 1:3, :);
elseif (num_dimensions == 4)
    A1 = A(1:2, 1:3, :, :);
end
```

If the range of possible matrix dimensions is small this kind of if-else block keeps it simple.  It seems like you want some way to create an indexing tuple (e.g. (1:2,:,:,:) ) on the fly, which I don't know if there is a way to do.  You must match the correct number of dimensions with your indexing...if you index in fewer dimensions than the matrix has, matlab returns a value with the unindexed dimensions collapsed into a single array (similar to what you get with

```
A1 = A(:);
```

Comment: Surely you meant `elseif` and not `else if`

Comment: Ha ha...well, that's what happens when you constantly go between MATLAB, Python, and Java.  Duly noted and corrected.