# Can characters be used as indices?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

Let's define, for example,

```
x = 10:10:2000;
```

As is well known, integer values can be used as indices:

```
>> x(9)
ans =
    90
```

In Matlab, characters can often be used where a number would be expected, with Matlab doing the conversion automatically. For example, since the ASCII code of `'a'` is `97`,

```
>> 'a'+1
ans =
    98
```

Can characters be also used as indices? Does Matlab convert them into integers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## They can be used... but careful if the index is a single colon!

Let's define

```
>> x = 10:10:2000;
```

Indexing with `'a'` produces the 97-th element of `x`, as expected:

```
>> x('a')
ans =
   970
```

However, indexing with **`':'` is a special case**. The string `':'` acts as a `:` index, thus producing a column vector of all values of `x`. That is, `x(':')` is the same as `x(:)`:

```
>> x(':')
ans =
          10
          20
          30
         ...
        1990
        2000
```

This means that the index `':'` is being **evaluated** (`x(':')` acts like `x(:)`), whereas other character arrays used as indices are **not evaluated** (`x('a')` doesn't act like `x(a)`):

```
>> a = 1;
>> x('a')
ans =
   970
```

This also implies that with `':'`, converting to a numeric type before indexing does matter, unlike with other characters used as indices:

```
>> x(double('abc'))
ans =
   970   980   990
>> x('abc')
ans =
   970   980   990

>> x(double(':'))
ans =
   580
>> x(':')
ans =
          10
          20
          30
         ...
        1990
        2000
```

The "evaluated" behaviour of `':'` used as index was [already known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537326/on-shape-agnostic-slicing-of-ndarrays). What's surprising is the contrast with other characters or character arrays used as indices (which are not evaluated).

The examples have used a single dimension for simplicity, but the described behaviour also applies to multidimensional indexing. The same behaviour is observed in Octave too.

Comment: One thing I don't get is this: how the hell did Octave know to test for this?:) Could have `subsref` been open-source in the early days?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Good point! See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537326/on-shape-agnostic-slicing-of-ndarrays#comment34308905_22539481)

Comment: Oh, very funky post, and also gives a legit reason for this odd behaviour.

Comment: @AndrasDeak The `':'` (string) index is mentioned [here](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/indexed-reference.html): _A colon used as an index is passed [...] as the colon character `':'`. Ranges specified using a colon (e.g., `2:5`) are expanded to `2 3 4 5`._

Comment: So it's *technically* not undocumented, only for all intents and purposes;)

Comment: Nice post @LuisMendo. I'll have to file this away in the back of my mind. I'm sure it will come in handy in the future when someone wants to combine multiple variables into a *useful* datastructure.

Comment: @Suever Thanks! Using `':'` as a colon is useful indeed (as in the answer I linked). But for Matlab to have a specific character singled out that way is weird