# How can all dimensions left after the specified one be preserved, without explicitly listing them?

Tags: matlab, numpy

<sup>Or equivalently, "what is the equivalent of NumPy's ellipsis indexing in Matlab"</sup>

Say I have some high-dimensional array:

```
x = zeros(3, 4, 5, 6);
```

I want to write a function that takes an array of size `(3, ...)`, and does some computation. In NumPy, I could write this:

```python
def fun(x):
    return x[0]*x[1] + x[2]
```

However, the equivalent in MATLAB doesn't work, because indexing with one integer flattens the array to 1d

```
function y = fun_bad(x)
    y = x(1)*x(2) + x(3)
```

I can make this work for up to 3-dimensional arrays with

```
function y = fun_ok3d(x)
    y = x(1,:,:)*x(2,:,:) + x(3,:,:)
```

If I want this to work for up to 10-dimensional arrays, I can write

```
function y = fun_ok10d(x)
    y = x(1,:,:,:,:,:,:,:,:,:)*x(2,:,:,:,:,:,:,:,:,:) + x(3,:,:,:,:,:,:,:,:,:)
```

How can I avoid writing stupid numbers of colons here, and just make this work for any dimension? Is there some `x(1,...)` syntax that implies this?

NumPy can use the `...` (`Ellipsis`) literal in an indexing expression to mean *"`:` as many times as needed"*, which would solve this problem.

Comment: AFAIK MATLAB requires explicit listing all dimensions. So,I would go with the reshaping method if such a functionality is needed and reshaping is almost free in both NumPy and MATLAB environments.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Approach 1: using a comma-separated list with `':'`

I don't know a way to specify

> `:` as many times as needed

while preserving shape. But you can specify

> `:` an *arbitrary* number of times

where that number of times is defined *at run-time*. With this method you can preserve shape, provided that the number of indices coincides with the number of dimensions.

This is done using a [comma-separated list](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) generated from a cell array, and exploiting the fact that [the *string* `':'` can be used as an index instead of `:`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22537326/2586922):

```matlab
function y = fun(x)
colons = repmat({':'}, 1, ndims(x)-1); % row cell array containing the string ':'
                                       % repeated the required number of times
y = x(1,colons{:}).*x(2,colons{:}) + x(3,colons{:});
```

This approach can be easily generalized to **indexing along any dimension**, not just the first:

```matlab
function y = fun(x, dim)
% Input argument dim is the dimension along which to index
colons_pre = repmat({':'}, 1, dim-1);
colons_post = repmat({':'}, 1, ndims(x)-dim);
y = x(colons_pre{:}, 1, colons_post{:}) ...
  .*x(colons_pre{:}, 2, colons_post{:}) ...
  + x(colons_pre{:}, 3, colons_post{:});
```

### Approach 2: splitting the array

You can split the array along the first dimension using [`num2cell`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html), and then apply the operation to the resulting subarrays. Of course this uses more memory; and as [noted by @Adriaan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42488245/2586922) it is slower.

```matlab
function y = fun(x)
xs = num2cell(x, [2:ndims(x)]); % x split along the first dimension
y = xs{1}.*xs{2} + xs{3};
```

Or, for indexing **along any dimension**:

```matlab
function y = fun(x, dim)
xs = num2cell(x, [1:dim-1 dim+1:ndims(x)]); % x split along dimension dim
y = xs{1}.*xs{2} + xs{3};
```

Answer (score 15):

MATLAB flattens all trailing dimensions when using a single colon, so you can use that to get from your *N*-D array to a 2D array, which you can [`reshape`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) back into the original *N* dimensions after the calculation.

### Along the first dimension

If you want to use the first dimension you can use a relatively simple and short piece of code:

```matlab
function y = MyMultiDimensional(x)
    x_size = size(x); % Get input size
    yflat = x(1,:) .* x(2,:) + x(3,:); % Calculate "flattened" 2D function
    y = reshape(yflat, [1 x_size(2:end)]); % Reshape output back to original size
end
```

### Along an arbitrary dimension, now featuring N-D permute.

When you want your function to act along the *n*-th dimension out of a total of *N*, you can [`permute`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) that dimension to the front first:

```matlab
function y = MyMultiDimensional(x,n)
    x_size = size(x); % Get input size

    Order = 1:numel(x_size);
    Order(n)=[]; % Remove n-th dimension
    Order2 = [n, Order]; % Prepend n-th dimension

    xPermuted = permute(x,Order2); % permute the n-th dimension to the front
    yTmp = xPermuted (1,:) .* xPermuted (2,:) + xPermuted (3,:); % Calculate "flattened" 2D function
    y = reshape(yTmp, x_size(Order)); % Reshape output back to original size
end
```

I timed the results of the two methods of Luis' and my methods:

```
function timeMultiDim()

x = rand(1e1,1e1,1e1,1e1,1e1,1e1,1e1,1e1);

    function y = Luis1(x)
        colons = repmat({':'}, 1, ndims(x)-1); % row cell array containing the string ':'
        % repeated the required number of times
        y = x(1,colons{:}).*x(2,colons{:}) + x(3,colons{:});
        
    end

    function y = Luis2(x)
        xs = num2cell(x, [2:ndims(x)]); % x split along the first dimension
        y = xs{1}.*xs{2} + xs{3};
    end

    function y = Adriaan(x)
        x_size = size(x); % Get input size
        yflat = x(1,:) .* x(2,:) + x(3,:); % Calculate "flattened" 2D function
        y = reshape(yflat, [1 x_size(2:end)]); % Reshape output back to original size
    end

n=1;
    function y = Adriaan2(x,n)
        x_size = size(x); % Get input size
        
        Order = 1:numel(x_size);
        Order(n)=[]; % Remove n-th dimension
        Order2 = [n, Order]; % Prepend n-th dimension
        
        xPermuted = permute(x,Order2); % permute the n-th dimension to the front
        yTmp = xPermuted (1,:) .* xPermuted (2,:) + xPermuted (3,:); % Calculate "flattened" 2D function
        y = reshape(yTmp, x_size(Order)); % Reshape output back to original size
        
    end

t1 = timeit(@() Luis1(x));
t2 = timeit(@() Luis2(x));
t3 = timeit(@() Adriaan(x));
t4 = timeit(@() Adriaan2(x,n));

format long g;
fprintf('Luis 1: %f seconds\n', t1);
fprintf('Luis 2: %f seconds\n', t2);
fprintf('Adriaan 1: %f seconds\n', t3);
fprintf('Adriaan 2: %f seconds\n', t4);

end

Luis 1: 0.698139 seconds
Luis 2: 4.082378 seconds
Adriaan 1: 0.696034 seconds
Adriaan 2: 0.691597 seconds
```

So, going to a cell is bad, it takes more than 5 times as long, `reshape` and `':'` are barely apart, so that'd come down to preference.