# Transform matlab function output (cell array) into comma separated list without temporary cell array

Tags: matlab, cell, inline

As by the title, how can a cell array that is the output of a matlab function be directly turned into a comma-separated list without using a temporary array?

I.e., I know you can write

```
% functioning code
tmp = cell(1,3); % function that makes a temporary cell_array;
b = ndgrid(tmp{:}); % transform tmp into a 
% comma-separated list and pass into another function
```

I am looking for a way that allows me to do this in a way like

```
% non functioning code
b = ndgrid( cell(1,3){:} );
```

so that it can be used within an anonymous function, where no temporary arguments are allowed. Example:

```
fun = @(x)accept_list( make_a_cell(x){:} );
```

How could this be achieved? 
I would think that there must be a function invoked when the operator '{:}' is used, but which one would it be?

EDIT for clarification:

The solution in the answer which this question was tagged to possibly be a duplicate of does not solve the problem, because subsref is not a replacement for {:} when creating a comma-separated list.

Example:

```
a = {1:2,3:4}
[A1,A2] = ndgrid(subsref(a, struct('type', '{}', 'subs', {{':'}})));
```

is (wrongly)

```
A1 =
     1     1
     2     2
A2 =
     1     2
     1     2
```

but

```
a = {1:2,3:4}    
[A1,A2] = ndgrid(a{:});
```

returns (correctly)

```
A1 =
     1     1
     2     2
A2 =
     3     4
     3     4
```

Comment: Why  is a  one-liner necessary? What added advantage do you think you'll get?

Comment: I added some clarification in an edit below the question. Unfortunately the proposed solution does not work.

Comment: So create a temporary anonymous function to call in actual anonymous function. I don't see any real need for a one-liner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer is (see comments of Sardar Usama in the comments above) to replace

```
fun = @(x)accept_list( make_a_cell(x){:} );
```

by

```
tmpfun = @(cell_arg, fun_needs_list)fun_needs_list( cell_arg{:} );
fun = @(x)tmpfun(make_a_cell(x), accept_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [string ':' as an index.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22539481/2630666)  This syntax always looks weird to me but it works in many cases.  In your example

```
tmp = cell(1,3);
b = ndgrid(tmp{:})

b =

   Empty array: 0-by-0-by-0

    b = ndgrid( cell(1,3){:} )
Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.
```

Now if you create a dummy variable say `s = {':'};`  Then you can get around the error by doing this:

```
b = ndgrid( cell(1,3){s{1}} )

b =

   Empty array: 0-by-0-by-0
```

Another option is to simply use the`':'` directly.  `b = ndgrid( cell(1,3){':'} );`

Here is an example using `num2cell`

```
A = reshape(1:12,4,3);
A(:,:,2) = A*10;
a = {A, 1};
num2cell(a{':'})

ans(:,:,1) = 

    [4x1 double]    [4x1 double]    [4x1 double]


ans(:,:,2) = 

    [4x1 double]    [4x1 double]    [4x1 double]
a = {A, 2};
num2cell(a{':'})

ans(:,:,1) = 

    [1x3 double]
    [1x3 double]
    [1x3 double]
    [1x3 double]


ans(:,:,2) = 

    [1x3 double]
    [1x3 double]
    [1x3 double]
    [1x3 double]
```

Comment: That is very interesting, thanks! Unfortunately, it only works with some functions. It doesn't with e.g. num2cell.

Comment: @SteffenWolp it works just fine with `num2cell` provided the values are correct.

Comment: Ok, right. What I had in mind was that e.g., `ndgrid( num2cell(a){':'} )` doesn't work.